# How to use eventfilter and installeventfilter methods?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using python 3.8 and qt5 for the desktop app.

I want to delete selected `QTreeWidgetItem` when the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is pressed.

I tried the below code, but it did not work:

```
class EventFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass

    def eventFilter(self, a0: 'QObject', a1: 'QEvent') -> bool:
        if isinstance(a1, QKeyEvent) and a1.matches(QKeySequence_StandardKey=QKeySequence.Delete):
            print("event filter")
            pass
        return super().eventFilter(a0, a1)

treeWidget.installEventFilter(EventFilter())
# treeWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(EventFilter())
```

Some posts said to install on viewport, but that did not work either.

This is my app's structure:

```
QMainWindow
-- QTabWidget
---- QTreeWidget
```

Can you give me some hints on how to use `eventfilter` and `installeventfilter`, or any other recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the cause of the problem is the scope of the EventFilter object since not being assigned to a variable it will be eliminated instantly. A possible solution is to assign a variable that has sufficient scope, another option is to pass it a parent since it is a QObject, in this case I will use the second.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QTreeWidget


class EventFilter(QObject):
    delete_pressed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.matches(QKeySequence.Delete):
                self.delete_pressed.emit()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tabWidget)
        treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
        tabWidget.addTab(treeWidget, "Tree")

        eventFilter = EventFilter(treeWidget)
        eventFilter.delete_pressed.connect(self.handle_delete_pressed)

    def handle_delete_pressed(self):
        print("delete pressed")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

On the other hand, it is not neccesary to reinvent the wheel since there are already QShortcuts that serve to detect when the user presses key combinations

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QShortcut,
    QTabWidget,
    QTreeWidget,
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tabWidget)
        treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
        tabWidget.addTab(treeWidget, "Tree")

        shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence.Delete, treeWidget)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.handle_delete_pressed)

    def handle_delete_pressed(self):
        print("delete pressed")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```